# Setting an identical map extent for all systems resolutions with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, extents

I want to see my map extent as identical in all resolutions (17 inches, 20 inches etc).

If I set centre and zoom together, the map extent is varying with respect to different machine resolutions.

```
view: new olView({
            center: [312234.8270497762,2636116.2213047906],
           // extent: mapExtent,
            projection: this.projection,          
            rotation: 0,
            zoom: 8
          })
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Calling fit() will fit an extent to the viewport and give similar coverage (although full screen on wide and standard monitors will always differ) but the zoom level might change as a result e.g. `map.getView().fit([302234,2536116,322234,2736116]);` will fit to give 10km coverage around your center.